# 16.04 Supported 10G Network Cards

Tags: networking

I need a 10G network card for my Ubuntu 16.04 machine.  I want to know where the list of supported hardware is so I can check before I buy.  The card of interest currently is: Myricom 10G-PCIE2-8B2-2S

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

This older post suggests that it is: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/recommendations-for-a-10gb-network-card-4175471913/

```
The following dual SFP+ adapters all work in Linux:
Broadcom 57810S (bnx2x driver)
Myricom 10G-PCIE2-8B2-2S (myri10ge driver)
Intel 82599, X520-DA2/82599EB, X540-T2 (ixgbe/ixgbevf driver)
```

The referenced driver exists in Ubuntu 17.10 which you can verify with:

```
modinfo myri10ge
```

The required firmware exists in /lib/firmware:

```
/lib/firmware/myri10ge_eth_big_z8e.dat
/lib/firmware/myri10ge_eth_z8e.dat
/lib/firmware/myri10ge_ethp_big_z8e.dat
/lib/firmware/myri10ge_ethp_z8e.dat
/lib/firmware/myri10ge_rss_eth_big_z8e.dat
/lib/firmware/myri10ge_rss_eth_z8e.dat
/lib/firmware/myri10ge_rss_ethp_big_z8e.dat
/lib/firmware/myri10ge_rss_ethp_z8e.dat
```